# Can't create support request in Asure, despite correct subscription

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Creation of new support request in Azure shows only Recommended solution on second step. Process of creation become interupted and steps 3. Additional details and 4. Review + create become unavailable.
How to create support reques in appropriate way?

I tryied to create New support request from Help + support page and from resource page, i tryied to compose Summary in differents way tryied to choosing differents Problem type but at rezult Azure shows to mу only recomendation steps without ability to create support ticket

Comment: It's indeed quiet a UX-Nightmare since first a 4-step process is shown but then the process bars vanishes and the buttons to actually create a request are hidden at the bottom of the page.
I guess it's a trick to keep people from submitting tickets to early.... x(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the recommended steps didn't help just go back one step and search for creating a support ticket.
It is a little misleading at first.

[image]

Then continue with the steps:

[image]